# SVG Issue with Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, compatibility

Since 2022 I have noticed a problem with a circular svg that worked fine before. The svg only bugs under chrome.

**Edge**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

**Opera/Chrome**

[image]

Code :

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 300" class="a-scrollIndicator__text">
                <defs>
                    <path id="txt-path" d=" M 150, 150 m -60, 0 a 60,60 0 0,1 120,0 a 60,60 0 0,1 -120,0 "></path>
                </defs>
                <text dy="0" font-size="15">
                    <textPath startOffset="0" xlink:href="#txt-path" side="left" method="align" style="fill:transparent;text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-family: MonumentBold;stroke: white;stroke-width: 0.3;">
                        SCROLL • SCROLL •
                    </textPath>

                    <textPath startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#txt-path" side="left" method="align" style="fill:transparent;text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-family: MonumentBold;stroke: white;stroke-width: 0.3;">
                        SCROLL • SCROLL •
                    </textPath>
                </text>
            </svg>
```

Comment: report Chrome bugs to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *probably* a problem with putting two `<textPath>` elements under a single `<text>` in Chrome. Fixed by enveloping each `<textPath>` with a `<text>` element:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 300 300" class="a-scrollIndicator__text">
  <defs>
 <path id="txt-path" d=" M 150, 150 m -60, 0 a 60,60 0 0,1 120,0 a 60,60 0 0,1 -120,0 "></path>
  </defs>
  <text dy="0" font-size="15">
<textPath startOffset="0" xlink:href="#txt-path" side="left" method="align" style="fill:transparent;text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-family: MonumentBold;stroke: white;stroke-width: 0.3;">
 SCROLL • SCROLL •
</textPath>
  </text>
  <text dy="0" font-size="15">
<textPath startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#txt-path" side="left" method="align" style="fill:transparent;text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-family: MonumentBold;stroke: white;stroke-width: 0.3;">
 SCROLL • SCROLL •
</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```